# Mongodb php extension loaded but class not found

Tags: php, mongodb, laravel

I've download and install mongo and it's woring just fine, but when i tried to use it with Laravel I get some problems.

I downloaded mongodb PHP (TS) extension from pecl https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.4.0/windows and add it to my php extension

[image]

I've read other solutions but it just don't work; 
The Class 'MongoDB\Driver\Manager' not found and even when i add `phpinfo()` in a page It doesn't display any mongodb extension

I'm using php 7.0 and wamp64 btw.

Comment: Did you restart your server after installing the extension?

Comment: Yeah, I did. Like I show in the image I have the ext enabled in wamp UI

Comment: can you show you connection config file plz without password ofcourse

Comment: @MarouaneSihad Then you haven't installed it correctly. Or maybe you have installed it for CLI and not for the server? Maybe you've installed it for PHP 7.0, but your local server runs PHP 7.1 There are many variables in this.

Answer (score 0):

You need to download exact dll file which is match with your PHP version. phpinfo() will not show Mongodb if version doesn't match.

Ensure the following things and download the correct dll file.

1) Your php version

2) Your system architecture (64 or 86)

3) Whether Thread safety enabled or not (You can check this in phpinfo())

[Download DLL here](https://pecl.php.net/package/mongodb/1.2.7/windows)